# jQuery index of the object in array

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the index of the trigger element in the array.

The html looks like this:

```
<ul>
     <li><a href="#" rel="group">Link 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" rel="group">Link 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" rel="group">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then on click I'm calling the run() method of the obJ object:

```
var obJ = {
    run : function(obj) {
        var att = obj.attr('rel');
        var arr = jQuery.find('a[rel='+att+']');
        alert(obj.indexOf(arr));
    }   
};
$(function() {
    $('a.click').click(function() {
        obJ.run($(this));
        return false;
    });
});
```

The above however doesn't give me the index of the trigger in the collected array.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `jQuery.index()`.

```
var obj = {
    run: function(obj) {
        var att = obj.attr('rel');
        var index = $('a[rel='+att+']').index(obj);
    }   
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't you mean this?

```
alert(arr.indexOf(obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

Mike Haboustak's answer is probably the best way of doing it but you could also do something like

```
$('a.click').each(function(index, o){
   $(o).click(function () { obj.run($(o), index); return false; });
});
```

Similar result slightly different approach.